# Lightdm will not autostart

Tags: boot, startx, lightdm

My issue is with Lightdm, it will not autostart, keeps going to CLI. From there I can type startx and it works fine.
I have run raspi-config to set boot straight to desktop, seems to have been ignored.
I have also ran "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm".

I'm pretty new at this so I have no idea where to look.
I'd like to have systemctl handling this as it was supposed to.

Comment: Welcome.  Edit in the output from `systemctl  get-default` and `systemctl status lightdm`.

Comment: Right, that gave me something to look. The first one says graphical.target.
The second one had:

● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-03-18 00:31:57 WET; 12min ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
  Process: 674 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: and
`lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.`